# Combine two regression models when variables are highly correlated

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I investigated the relation between an angle $\alpha$ and a sensor value $x$. So I have $\alpha = f(x)$ which can be modeled here as a simple polynom.

When I want to use this relationship in a real system I have the problem that I need the value $\alpha$ with a high frequency, but the sensor is rather slow. So I tried to model $x = f(t)$ and $t$ is the time from a high frequency clock. Once again, a polynomial model is sufficient here.

Is it possible to combine these two models in the form $\alpha = f(x,t)$. I believe a normal multiple regression is not possible because $x$ and $t$ are highly correlated. Are there alternative methods I can use?

Edit:
I'm not sure, but is this an example of a mediation situation?